# aop aspects as mock in spring test

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4, spring-aop, spring-test

I came across an interesting article: [AOP Aspects as mocks in JUnit](http://www.octodecillion.com/aop-advice-as-mocks/)

Since I have requirement to mock multiple final and private static variables, I am planning to use AOP in place of reflection or PowerMockito as they are causing issues with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Is there any way I can use `@Aspect` for test classes without using the annotation `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`? (I want to use an aspect targeting class X only in one test case.)

This is a sample of what I want to do.

The question is answered(adding for discussion on what could be done)

```java
//External class 
public final class ABC(){
  public void method1() throws Exception {}
}
```

```java
@Service
public void DestClass() {
  private static final ABC abc = new ABC();

  public Object m() {
    // code (...)
    try {
      abc.method1();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      // do something (...)
      return null;
    }
    // more code (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with code of class to be tested ? I am trying to understand the requirement for AOP for a single class.

Comment: Also note that Spring AOP can only advice bean method calls.

Comment: Adding in question

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the code ?

Comment: Am trying to test catch block in the code only in class, if I use aop in all classes, then catch block can execute right.

Comment: Could you please describe how do you want to test the catch block ? Is the requirement to throw exception when `abc.method1()` is called and then to verify `null` is returned ? How was Spring AOP planned to be implemeted?

Comment: I have a solution. Since ABC is external file, am planning to have abc.method1() in a separate method(also, it is called in multiple methods of DestClass. If it is internal, I can skip creating a method. Now, I will have an aspect  and before new method is executed, I will use aspect and throw execption.

Comment: So updated code in place of try catch : `Object nw= newMethod(); if(nw == null) return null; else {/*Do nothing and continue as above*/} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring framework allows to programmatically create proxies that advise target objects , without configuring through `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` or `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`

Details can be found in the documentation section : [Programmatic Creation of @AspectJ Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aspectj-programmatic) and the implementation is pretty simple.

Example code from the documentation.

```
// create a factory that can generate a proxy for the given target object
AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory(targetObject);

// add an aspect, the class must be an @AspectJ aspect
// you can call this as many times as you need with different aspects
factory.addAspect(SecurityManager.class);

// you can also add existing aspect instances, the type of the object supplied must be an @AspectJ aspect
factory.addAspect(usageTracker);

// now get the proxy object...
MyInterfaceType proxy = factory.getProxy();
```

Please note that with Spring AOP , only method executions can be adviced. Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn)

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans). Field
>   interception is not implemented, although support for field
>   interception could be added without breaking the core Spring AOP APIs.
>   If you need to advise field access and update join points, consider a
>   language such as AspectJ.

The document shared with the question is about aspectj and without providing the sample code to be adviced it is hard to conclude if the requriement can acheived through Spring AOP. The document mentions this as well.

> One example of the integration of AspectJ is the Spring framework,
>   which now can use the AspectJ pointcut language in its own AOP
>   implementation. **Spring’s implementation is not specifically targeted
>   as a test solution**.

Hope this helps.

--- Update : A test case without using AOP ---

Consider the external Class

```
public class ABCImpl implements ABC{

    @Override
    public void method1(String example) {
        System.out.println("ABC method 1 called :"+example);
    }
}
```

And the `DestClass`

```
@Service
public class DestClass {

    private static final ABC service = new ABCImpl();

    protected ABC abc() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("DestClass.abc() called");
        return service;
    }

    public Object m() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        try {
            abc().method1("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+ e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return obj;

    }
}
```

Following test class autowires the `DestClass` bean with overridden logic to throw exception . This code can be modified to adapt to your requirement.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DestClassSpringTest.TestConfiguration.class })
public class DestClassSpringTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DestClass destClass() {
            return new DestClass() {
                protected ABC abc() throws Exception {
                //  super.abc(); // not required . added to demo the parent method call
                    throw new Exception("Custom exception thrown");
                }
            };

        }
    }

    @Autowired
    DestClass cut;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Object obj = cut.m();
        assertNull(obj);
    }
}
```

Following will be the output log

```
DestClass.abc() called // this will not happen if the parent method call is commented in  DestClassSpringTest.TestConfiguration
Exception : Custom exception thrown
```

Comment: Hi, The issue is abc in real an interface and abcimpl is final and thats why I directly added abc as final class

Comment: I am not modifying anything related to ABC , the trick here is the overridden `protected ABC abc() throws Exception` method in `DestClassSpringTest.TestConfiguration`. Could you please update the question if the requirement is different

Answer (score 0):

The article you are referring to is using full AspectJ, not Spring AOP. Thus, you do not need any `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` for that, just

- **either** the AspectJ load-time weaver on the command line when running your test via `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`
- **or** the AspectJ compiler activated when compiling your tests (easily done via AspectJ Maven plugin if you use Maven)

Both approaches are completely independent of Spring, will work in any project and even when using Spring also work when targeting execution of third party code because no dynamic proxies are needed unlike in Spring AOP. So there is no need to make the target code into a Spring bean or to create a wrapper method in your application class for it. When using compile-time weaving you can even avoid weaving into the third party library by using `call()` instead of `execution()` pointcut. Spring AOP only knows `execution()`, AspectJ is more powerful.

By the way: Unfortunately both your question and your comment about the solution you found are somewhat fuzzy and I do not fully understand your requirement. E.g. you talked about mocking final and private static variables, which would also be possible in other ways with AspectJ by using `set()` and/or `get()` pointcuts. But actually it seems you do not need to mock the field contents, just stub the results of method calls upon the objects assigned to those fields.

Comment: you are right. I want to stub the results. I have not worked on aop and hence, do not have complete knowledge. Will look into the possibilities mentioned here. Thank you